# Integrate dropdown angular-strap with ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I want to template a cell as a dropdown button. So I created a cell template with a button linked to the dropdown directive. If I create this button outside the grid, it's working but inside the grid it's not. I am not sure but I guess the `$scope` is not accessible in the template.

I created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LaeuGk) that shows the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me. The problem is relating to the CSS of `.ngCell`. Currently the `overflow` property is set to `hidden`. Try add this to your css file to overwrite the property

```
.ngCell {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: It fixes the issue, I'll open an issue on the ng-grid project.