# Implement a Bootstrap Dropdown in ng-grid of Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use a dropdown box in headerCellTemplate property of ng-grid. The columnDefs looks like this

```
   columnDefs: [{field:'dt', displayName:'Time', width:'**', cellFilter:'date:\"HH:mm:ss\"',headerClass:'grad1',cellTemplate:'<div><center>{{row.getProperty(\'dt\')|timefilter}}</center></div>'},
 {field:'rl', displayName:'Impact',cellTemplate:'<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><center><img  ng-src="{{row.getProperty(\'rl\') | dateformat1}}"</img></center></div>',width:'80px',sortFn:impSortFn,headerClass:'grad1',headerCellTemplate:"impactHeader.html"}, ]
```

The headerCell Template use a impactHeader.html file that looks like this

```
    <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Impact<span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="#">OptA</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">OptB</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">OptC</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I can see dropdown inserted to the header of the table but the dropdown is not visible. i.e. I can't see OptA , OptB and OptC. Am I missing something?

Thanks!!

Comment: Bootstrap's dropdowns relies on JS. To get this working right with angular you should write directives. There're a bunch of directives for Bootstrap here http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: You can check 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521645/integrate-dropdown-angular-strap-with-ng-grid

Regards,

Darshan JOSHI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the result as follows.

Angular JS allows you to add a HTML file as template to your table header.

So, you can define your own template (which will be simple HTML file like this)

let's say you have a file named **headerTemplate.html** which looks like this

```
 <div class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">DropDown</div>
```

and now you can use this dropdown usign the `HeaderCellTemplate` in `columnDefs` like the one in question.

Now simply override `ng-grid` css to `visible` Refer to the useful link provided by @Darshan in comment below.